# New fetch not working for components in nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm having troubles with the new fetch method and full static in v2.13.X.

It works fine in page components, but I can't make it work in components using the new component module. It simply won't fire... I read all the documentations to see if I was wrong assuming it would work in full static or with the new components module, but I couldn't find anything close to what's going on with my code. Actually, I tried with Universal mode and it didn't work either.

I'm doing the following:

**./components/test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>test</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  fetch() {
    console.log(`test me`)
  }
}
</script>
```

If I use this component in any page, it won't print anything in the console, if I copy and paste the fetch() method as it is in any page component, it'll print the message.

Anybody knows why it won't work in components loaded through the [new component module](https://github.com/nuxt/components) in Nuxt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I forgot that I installed Nuxt globally when I was first testing it out.
That's why the new "fetch" method didn't work, because the global version was still way back in v2.8.X

Simply `npm i -g nuxt`

Found in: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/97#issuecomment-639106282